# Do you need SafeMath in Solidity version 0.8+ , and if not, can you still import it?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, evm

I have a solidity smart contract like this `pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;` can I still import SafeMath even if it's not needed for 0.8+ ? Since SafeMath is working with 0.7, but my contract specifies it accepts 0.7.0 up to lower than 0.9.0 what will SafeMath do in this case.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The SafeMath library validates if an arithmetic operation would result in an integer overflow/underflow. If it would, the library throws an exception, effectively reverting the transaction.

Since Solidity 0.8, the overflow/underflow check is implemented on the language level - it adds the validation to the bytecode during compilation.

You don't need the SafeMath library for Solidity 0.8+. You're still free to use it in this version, it will just perform the same validation twice (one on the language level and one in the library).

And it's strongly recommended to use it in 0.7, since the validation is **not** performed on the language level in this version yet.

---

So if you allow your contract to be compiled in both versions, you should include the library.

```
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

library SafeMath {
  function add(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256 c) {
    c = a + b;
    assert(c >= a);
    return c;
  }
}

contract MyContract {
    using SafeMath for uint256;
    
    function foo() external pure {
        uint256 number = 1;
        number.add(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: ok and what happens if you don't use SafeMath and an overflow/underflow occurs, does it revert the transaction but end up costing more gas?

Comment: @msa720 In v0.8, the transaction reverts... In v0.7, the number just overflows or underflows. For example you have an `uint8` (min value 0, max value 255), with value 0. If you subtract 1 from this number, it underflows, resulting in 255.

Comment: @PetrHejda what if I need to perform division e.g. 5/2, can solidity 0.8 do it without rounding or I should use SafeMath in this case?

Comment: @gigs The EVM doesn't support decimal numbers. Solidity is able to calculate 5/2 but it casts to an integer (i.e. rounds down) as soon as it's stored on the EVM level (either to memory or storage)... SafeMath "only" prevents integer overflow and underflow but it's not related to working with decimals... A usual workaround, if you need to work with decimal numbers, is to store values multiplied by `10 ^ decimals`. For example you declare that your contract uses 2 decimal places, and then store the value of `1` as `100`.

Comment: @PetrHejda ok then, as I understand you right we should apply decimal multiplication only for the first number e.g. 500/2, correct?

Comment: @gigs Correct, assuming you're using 2 decimal places.

Answer (score 1):

```
 * @dev Wrappers over Solidity's arithmetic operations with added overflow
 * checks.
 *
 * Arithmetic operations in Solidity wrap on overflow. This can easily result
 * in bugs, because programmers usually assume that an overflow raises an
 * error, which is the standard behaviour in high-level programming languages.
 * `SafeMath` restores this intuition by reverting the transaction when an
 * operation overflows.
 *
 * Using this library instead of the unchecked operations eliminates an entire
 * class of bugs, so it's recommended to use it always.
 */
library SafeMath {
    /**
     * @dev Returns the addition of two unsigned integers, reverting on
     * overflow.
     *
     * Counterpart to Solidity's `+` operator.
     *
     * Requirements:
     * - Addition cannot overflow.
     */
    function add(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        uint256 c = a + b;
        require(c >= a, "SafeMath: addition overflow");

        return c;
    }

    /**
     * @dev Returns the subtraction of two unsigned integers, reverting on
     * overflow (when the result is negative).
     *
     * Counterpart to Solidity's `-` operator.
     *
     * Requirements:
     * - Subtraction cannot overflow.
     */
    function sub(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        return sub(a, b, "SafeMath: subtraction overflow");
    }

    /**
     * @dev Returns the subtraction of two unsigned integers, reverting with a custom message on
     * overflow (when the result is negative).
     *
     * Counterpart to Solidity's `-` operator.
     *
     * Requirements:
     * - Subtraction cannot overflow.
     *
     * _Available since v2.4.0._
     */
    function sub(uint256 a, uint256 b, string memory errorMessage) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        require(b <= a, errorMessage);
        uint256 c = a - b;

        return c;
    }

    /**
     * @dev Returns the multiplication of two unsigned integers, reverting on
     * overflow.
     *
     * Counterpart to Solidity's `*` operator.
     *
     * Requirements:
     * - Multiplication cannot overflow.
     */
    function mul(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        // Gas optimization: this is cheaper than requiring 'a' not being zero, but the
        // benefit is lost if 'b' is also tested.
        // See: https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/pull/522
        if (a == 0) {
            return 0;
        }

        uint256 c = a * b;
        require(c / a == b, "SafeMath: multiplication overflow");

        return c;
    }

    /**
     * @dev Returns the integer division of two unsigned integers. Reverts on
     * division by zero. The result is rounded towards zero.
     *
     * Counterpart to Solidity's `/` operator. Note: this function uses a
     * `revert` opcode (which leaves remaining gas untouched) while Solidity
     * uses an invalid opcode to revert (consuming all remaining gas).
     *
     * Requirements:
     * - The divisor cannot be zero.
     */
    function div(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        return div(a, b, "SafeMath: division by zero");
    }

    /**
     * @dev Returns the integer division of two unsigned integers. Reverts with a custom message on
     * division by zero. The result is rounded towards zero.
     *
     * Counterpart to Solidity's `/` operator. Note: this function uses a
     * `revert` opcode (which leaves remaining gas untouched) while Solidity
     * uses an invalid opcode to revert (consuming all remaining gas).
     *
     * Requirements:
     * - The divisor cannot be zero.
     *
     * _Available since v2.4.0._
     */
    function div(uint256 a, uint256 b, string memory errorMessage) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        // Solidity only automatically asserts when dividing by 0
        require(b > 0, errorMessage);
        uint256 c = a / b;
        // assert(a == b * c + a % b); // There is no case in which this doesn't hold

        return c;
    }

    /**
     * @dev Returns the remainder of dividing two unsigned integers. (unsigned integer modulo),
     * Reverts when dividing by zero.
     *
     * Counterpart to Solidity's `%` operator. This function uses a `revert`
     * opcode (which leaves remaining gas untouched) while Solidity uses an
     * invalid opcode to revert (consuming all remaining gas).
     *
     * Requirements:
     * - The divisor cannot be zero.
     */
    function mod(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        return mod(a, b, "SafeMath: modulo by zero");
    }

    /**
     * @dev Returns the remainder of dividing two unsigned integers. (unsigned integer modulo),
     * Reverts with a custom message when dividing by zero.
     *
     * Counterpart to Solidity's `%` operator. This function uses a `revert`
     * opcode (which leaves remaining gas untouched) while Solidity uses an
     * invalid opcode to revert (consuming all remaining gas).
     *
     * Requirements:
     * - The divisor cannot be zero.
     *
     * _Available since v2.4.0._
     */
    function mod(uint256 a, uint256 b, string memory errorMessage) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        require(b != 0, errorMessage);
        return a % b;
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).